# Pie chart inside doughnut on same canvas

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I want to create something like this: jsfiddle.net/moe2ggrd/1/

Except I want to have a pie chart filling the inside of the doughnut with different data, but in the same canvas.

How would I accomplish this? I am using https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, 
First you just remove existing canvas and then after create the same canvas to dom by script. 
After that you will able to create pie chart on the same canvas.